# speed up indexing subarrays in matlab?

Tags: matlab, indexing

How can I speed up the following operations? The bottleneck is the third line even though for large dimensions of A1, the forth line is quite fast. Does the third line actually make a copy of A(b,b) that is stored in A1?

```
A = randn(1000,1000);
b = [67   145   200   185    11   166    80   137   163   132   133    19]; %random 
A1 = A(b,b);
v=A1*A(2,b)';
```

Note that the following is just as slow so I just broke up that line into two parts to demonstrate that the third line above is the bottleneck.

```
v=A(b,b);*A(2,b)';
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this makes it faster as a replacement for the third line that you claim to be the bottleneck -

```
[x,y]= ndgrid(b,b);
A1 = A((y-1)*size(A,1)+x);
```

Or

```
A1 = A(bsxfun(@plus,(b-1)*size(A,1),b'));
```

---

**Edit:** After profiling with the above listed codes, the runtime performance doesn't look to have improved by a lot. You mentioned in the comments that you are using these codes in a loop multiple times and `b` varies. If the loop count was a small value and `b` was a constant between those loop iterations, one could have thought of performing all those matrix-vector multiplications across all iterations into one big matrix-matrix multiplication, but this isn't the case here. So, I would say at this point that the bottleneck with the `indexing` might have to stay.

Comment: just tried the `b = randperm(200,100);` but it doesn't run on Matlab R2009a. I don't know when they implemented the second parameter.

Comment: thanks, this actually makes it a bit slower. My problem is with the third line, the permutations were just given so I can formulate my problem. I am specifically trying to speed up the third line not the whole piece of code given.

Comment: @methane Are you sure the  third line is the bottleneck? I just tried with MATLAB profiler and seemed like `randn` is the guilty one here. Could you post the profiler results screenshot?

Comment: as I said, this is just an example, my code is much more complicated and b is created very differenetly but for the purposes of this question i made it just a random sequence. See changes above.

Comment: @methane How are you profiling your code? Are you using `MATLAB profiler` or `tic-toc` or `timeit` or something else?

Comment: definitely slow, 20s vs 117s for my whole program just changing this one line you suggested. I am using MATLAB profiler. DO you have suggestions how I should formulate my question more precisely?

Comment: @methane Just staying with your code, could you post the MATLAB profiler screnshot in your question? Just to prove your point that the line-3 is really the bottleneck. Use your actual data and everything and not `randn` that I believe was made up to formulate the question here.

Comment: 71.9% is spent in the third line, 11.7% in the fourth, when I merge the line as shown in my question the time is ~80%. I hope this proves my point.

Comment: @methane Just curious what are the sizes of A and b in your actual case?

Comment: A is fixed on the order of 5000x5000 and the size of b changes, from 5000 to 100 or so. So the operations above performed in a loop multiple times (minus the randperm and randn part which is just for the sake of formulating the question)

Comment: @methane Check out the edits. Edited `bsxfun` code seems to be an improvement over `ndgrid`, but not over your direct indexing code.